# multiprocessing unsatisfied by any arguments

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a list of numbers, I want to get 2 different cpu cores to print half the list each. 1 core starts at the beggining the other starts in the middle.

I have made 2 attempts. Both give errors that tell me to try my other attempt
[example of attempts and errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUEpi.png)

error 1 = too many arguments, only need 1

error 2 = 1 arg is non iterable

(make up your mind)

## code 1 (not iterating)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

A = np.linspace(0,99999999,999999)

def print_stuff(i):
    for j in i:    # i want two seperate proccessores to print half of this list each 
        print(A[j]) 

def do_stuff():
    print("doing stuff")
    kk = range(int(len(A/2)))
    kk2 = [] # to use to index places in the lists
    for i in kk:
        kk2.append(i+kk[-1])
    print(len(kk2))

    p1 = mp.Process(target = print_stuff, args = kk,)
    p2 = mp.Process(target = print_stuff, args = kk2,)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    # This will terminate the thread when they done their job(s)
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print("done stuff")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

## code 2 (iterating)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

A = np.linspace(0,99999999,999999)

def print_stuff(i):
    # i want two seperate proccessores to print half of this list each 
    print(A[j]) 

def do_stuff():
    print("doing stuff")
    kk = range(int(len(A/2)))
    kk2 = []
    for i in kk:
        kk2.append(i+kk[-1])
    print(len(kk2))
    for i in range(int(len(A/2))):
        p1 = mp.Process(target = print_stuff, args = kk[i],)
        p2 = mp.Process(target = print_stuff, args = kk2[i],)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()

    # This will terminate the thread when they done their job(s)
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
    print("done stuff")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code is problematic because you are passing an Iterable where an integer is required.

Answer (score 0):

for the first code you have to remember that the multiprocessing Process starts a new python interpreter and therefore the printing wont work
you can avoid this problem by using jpe_types.paralel.Process witch will overide the print statement in the processes so it will actually print to the console
the code would look like this

```
import jpe_types.paralel
import numpy as np

A = np.linspace(0,10,10)

def print_stuff(start):
    for j in range(start, len(A), 2):    # i want two seperate proccessores to print half of this list each 
        print(A[j]) 

def do_stuff():
    p1 = jpe_types.paralel.Process(target=print_stuff, args=(1,))
    p2 = jpe_types.paralel.Process(target=print_stuff, args=(0,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

however ther is no point as the overiden print statment simply puts everything in a multiprocessing Queue and has a thread in the main module that prints anything put in that Queue so you don't gain anything


for the second code
works file like this:
but note it will only work if A has an even length

```
import jpe_types.paralel
import numpy as np

A = np.linspace(0,10,10)

def print_stuff(j):
    # i want two seperate proccessores to print half of this list each 
    print(A[j]) 

def do_stuff():
    print("doing stuff")
    kk = range(int(len(A)/2)) # you want half the lentght
    kk2 = []
    for i in kk:
        kk2.append(i+kk[-1])
    for i in range(int(len(A/2))):
        p1 = jpe_types.paralel.Process(target = print_stuff, args = (kk[i],))
        p2 = jpe_types.paralel.Process(target = print_stuff, args = (kk2[i],))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()

    # This will terminate the thread when they done their job(s)
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
    print("done stuff")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

btw this code is significantly slower than just

```
for e in A:
   print(e)
```

as there is a lot of overhead involved in creating the Processes
hope that answers your question